# Akka how to conditionally froward request based on parameter value

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have an existing route similar to this:

```
pathPrefix("foo") {
  pathPrefix(IntNumber) { id =>
    post {
      entity(as[FooReqeust]) { request =>
        val f = doSomething(id, request)
        onComplete(f) {
          case Success(res) => complete(res)
          case Failure(e) => complete(HttpResponse(InternalServerError, entity = "someError"))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We have a new service (external to this one) which we wish to start routing to in the future after running some tests. the new service headers/parameters/post body etc. is identical to the existing

I'd like to forward requests from the existing endpoint to the new endpoint if the `id` answers some condition.

I'm not clear how to acheive this. (and want to avoid serialize/deserilize inspecting body etc.)

for instance:

```
pathPrefix("foo") {
  pathPrefix(IntNumber) { id =>
    post {
      if (id == 1234) complete(usingNewService(...)) <<<< blindly complete with the new service
      else  // use the current implementation
      entity(as[FooReqeust]) { request =>
        .... same code as before ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you use temporary redirects, ie 307 status code, and make the client re-do the request against the new service?

Comment: What do you mean by redirect? Http or forward the call (which can be easy if the endpoint is available as function)?

Comment: A http response with code 307 to the client to perform a call to a different endpoint because ` the new service headers/parameters/post body etc. is identical to the existing`

Comment: sorry, my bad the request is post and redirects are not possible here

Comment: updated the question to "forward requests"